# Executing Nginx from java application

Tags: java, nginx

I'm trying to start nginx HTTP server from java application using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

the command variable contents is :

```
/media/data/websites/php-desktop/bin/nginx/nginx/nginx -c "/tmp/conf/nginx.conf" -p "/media/data/websites/php-desktop/bin/nginx/"
```

the command should start nginx from teh path specified, with the config file after -c and with the prefix value after -p

the problem is java doesn't start nginx it just falls silently, i tried to print the procccess output put it doesn't output anything.

beside when i execute the command from any terminal it works fine.
Note: i use ubuntu linux, nginx built from source with latest stable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

is equivalent to

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, null);
```

So it won't work because the array of arguments is null and exetable file is "/media/data/websites/php-desktop/bin/nginx/nginx/nginx -c /tmp/conf/nginx.conf -p .... ".

Please try either of

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
  "/bin/sh"
  ,"-c"
  ,"/media/data/websites/php-desktop/bin/nginx/nginx/nginx -c \"/tmp/conf/nginx.conf\" -p \"/media/data/websites/php-desktop/bin/nginx/\"});
```

Or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
"/media/data/websites/php-desktop/bin/nginx/nginx/nginx", 
"-c", 
"/tmp/conf/nginx.conf", 
"-p", 
"/media/data/websites/php-desktop/bin/nginx/"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading off the process's inputStream. Something like this ...

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);  
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
        String line = null;  
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
            System.out.println(line);  
        }
```

Edit: also try the errorStream instead ...
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29
(that's probably where you'll find any errors!)

HTH

Comment: hmm - nothing from errorStream, eh. I guess you've tried calling another command, such as 'ls', which definitely won't have permissions problems or anything .. just another avenue to try. ..